# Can we create a folder in project and add images in it by user instead of bin?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

I am creating a desktop application in which user can add persons and their images. Currently, the images folder is in bin folder but when I publish the application and run on client pc then images folder gone missing.

**OR**

Can I add images in `Project->Properties->Resources` programmatically?

[image: Can i use this folder?]

Currently when I tried to user this Images Folder in `PMS Project` then images added in the folder present in the `bin folder`. How I can add in this folder?
Currently, I tried to access this is

```
string path = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();

Bitmap imgImage = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);

System.IO.File.Copy(ImageName, Path.Combine(appPath, CNIC + Path.GetFileName(ImageName)), true);
```

I also want to keep images folder in the installation folder.
But it goes in the bin folder. How I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

If you plan to have a private folder where your app store some data then you should really use the standard specs. You should create a folder inside the Environment.ApplicationData defined in the [SpecialFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.specialfolder?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) enum

You could have something like this in the startup code of your application

```
 string commonFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
 string appFolder = Path.Combine(commonFolder, "PMS");
 string imgFolder = Path.Combine(appFolder, "PoliceImages");
 Directory.CreateDirectory(imgFolder);
```

Now those strings variables should be stored inside some kind of global configuration static class where you can retrieve them in any part of your application

Comment: I added the first three lines of your code in common class and on startup i checked that if the directory is created or not. but now the image is not in the project folder and not in the **bin/PoliceImages** folder

Comment: Ok. i found the path which is C:\Users\Ali\AppData\Roaming\PMS\PoliceImages but i want to keep in the installation folder.

Comment: How i can retrieve images from AppData\Roaming in my application?
Should through this? 
**"C:\\Users\\System.Environment.MachineName\\AppData\\Roaming\\PoliceImages"**

Comment: You reach the folder in the same way you create the folder (Environment.SpecialFolder and Path.Combine). Here you store the images that your app acquires during its work. This is the pattern to follow if your image handling is dynamic. If you want to deploy some predefined images we should look at the installation system that you are planning to use. Do not use a folder for dynamic data inside your application folder. You will have many permissions problems and in some environments you will never be allowed to write in those folders.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the folder be created automatically, you can add the basic images that would go into that folder and mark their **Build Action** and **Copy to Output Directory** properties appropriately in their properties window. This will make sure the folder gets created and also images will be copied in published copy.

[image]

Alternatively, If there are no images from development time, you can create the folder in client's installed location, using System.IO classes. Like -

```
System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("ss")
```

However, I would like to mention that its not a good practice to allow users to add images into a sub folder in bin unless when it is going to be a part of application itself after adding. If it is a content or data, try to keep it out of the folder where application binaries are installed. Probably,

- Use an appropriate database storage.
- C:\Users\[USERNAME]\AppData\Roaming

  var directory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.AppData);

  OR

  var directory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
- Or simply D:\Temp\[ApplicationName]

Comment: You are right.. With steve ans i acheived this that images go in 
**C:\Users[USERNAME]\AppData\Roaming** but i want to take backup of the images by user. Should he go to this path and copy the folder?

Comment: How i can retrieve images from AppData\Roaming in my application?
Should through this? 
**"C:\\Users\\System.Environment.MachineName\\AppData\\Roaming\\PoliceImages"**